# Elevation contour lines with footage calls

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, contour

Does anyone know how to create contour elevation lines? I've never done it before as I am using ArcGIS 10.8. I am unable to find any datasets online for my AOI. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: A google of "how to generate contour lines using ArcGIS" returned nearly 700k results. I'm pretty sure it's possible.

Comment: Perhaps consider clarifying and/or re-phrasing your question. Do you mean "How do I generate contours in feet from elevation data in meters? Or are you asking "where can I find elevation data for area "X"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by:

1- you can use Digital Elevation Model (DEM) to create Contour lines:

- Download DEM for your study region from [USGS](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) website.

2- Open ArcGIS, and Add DEM you have Download.

- You can Extract your region from DEM by using *Extract by Mask* tool, if you have Polygon Layer of your region.

3- Create Contour for your Extracted DEM, By using *Contour* tool in Geospatial Toolbox.

- then window will be open, you can select your DEM and specify the interval of contour lines.